# How to extract items at specified locations from list of comma separated strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, csv, parsing

I have a list of comma separated strings and I need to extract 1-st and 3-rd items from all strings.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "1,2,3",
    "4,5,6",
    "7,8,9",
    "10,11,12"
};
List<Tuple<string, string>> parsed = new List<Tuple<string, string>>(list.Count);
foreach (string s in list)
{
    string[] items = s.Split(',');
    parsed.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(items[0], items[2]));
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, parsed.Select(p => p.Item1 +","+ p.Item2)));
Console.ReadLine();
```

That results:

> 1,3
> 4,6
> 7,9
> 10,12

But when I try to write it using LINQ, I can't get something simpler than:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> parsed = list.Select(
    s =>
    {
        string[] items = s.Split(',');
        return new Tuple<string, string>(items[0], items[2]);
    });
```

I was wondering if it's possible to get rid of that `{}` block and replace it with LINQ function calls. To be clear, I am asking this question only to increase my knowledge of the features and capabilities of LINQ, so, any suggestion is welcome.

**Edit:**

So far, all suggested codes call the `split` function twice. Is there a way to get the desired result just by calling it once? Something like:

```
var parsed = list.Select(s => s.Split(',').Magic(...));
```

Also, by that code sample above, I didn't mean first and last items. I really mean *items at specified locations*.

Comment: `string[] items = s.Split(',');` - something like this or like `new Tuple<string, string>(items.Split(',')[0], items.Split(',')[2]);`?

Comment: Do you really want the output to be in `Tuple`?

Comment: @MaciejLos, well, I really was thinking of something that does not take an extra `split`.

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty, back here I have to do `new MyClass(items[0], items[3], items[12], ...)`!

Comment: @saastn, modified the answer to avoid the multiple `Split`

Comment: @saastn, Updated the answer to avoid the `Split` multiple times, you can see my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with [C#7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) or above version, then you can write even in simpler manner,

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> parsed = list.Select(
    s => (s.Split(',')[0], s.Split(',')[2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> parsed = list.Select(
                s =>
                {
                    var spl = s.Split(',');
                    return new Tuple<string, string>(spl[0], spl[2]);
                    // return new MyClass(spl[0], spl[2], ... ,spl[n]);
                });
```

---

If you want the `,` separated list back by removing the middle number you can use the `Regex` to replace it.

```
IEnumerable<string> afterUpdate = list.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @",[0-9]*,", ","));
```

Output for this will be

```
{
    "1,3",
    "4,6",
    "7,9",
    "10,12"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help...

```
        //----------------Linq.----------------------
        
        //Data Source 
        var source = new List<string> { "1,2,3", "4,5,6", "7,8,9", "10,11,12" };
        //var sourceTest = new List<string> { "11,45,6,5,", "2,3,4,5,6", "1,7,40,30", "10,20,30,40,50" };
        //var sourceTest2 = new List<string> { "15,12,11,45,6,5,", "1,2,3,4,5,6", "1,7,9,40,30", "60,20,70,80,90,100" };
        //Query Creation
        var queryLambda = source.Select(item => new
                                    {
                                        FirstItem = item.Split(',').FirstOrDefault(),
                                        ThirdItem = item.Split(',').Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()
                                    }).ToList();
        var query = (from items in source
                     select new
                     {
                         FirstItem = items.Split(',').FirstOrDefault(),
                         ThirdItem = items.Split(',').Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()
                     }).ToList();

        //Query Execution
        queryLambda.ForEach(item => { Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new string[] { item.FirstItem, item.ThirdItem })); });
        Console.WriteLine();
        query.ForEach(item => { Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new string[] { item.FirstItem, item.ThirdItem })); });
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Why do you think calling `FirstOrDefault()` and `Skip()` is better than direct indexing?

Comment: They are safe way to go, indexing may be faster in a small set, but using this you don't have to care about the source length, In indexing you have to check index[] exists but FirstOrDefault() safely return you null, Just a thought